# this.props.dispatch is not a function in react js component file

Tags: reactjs, dispatch

In pagination 'onSelect' event I am calling an function that is define outside of render and in component's class. But when event firing below error coming -

`BlogList.js:101 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function`

here is my code snippit -

```
import React from 'react'; 
import StaticLayout from '../Layout/StaticLayout';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getBlogList } from '../actions/signupActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import dateFormat from 'dateformat';

import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'; 
import queryString from 'query-string'


class BlogList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Blogs";

        this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBlogList();
    }

    render(){

        //===pagination variable========
        const per_page = 1;
        let pages = 0;
        if(this.props.blogListData !== undefined){
            pages = Math.ceil(this.props.blogListData.count / per_page) ;
        } 
        const current_page = this.props.page;
        const start_offset = (current_page - 1) * per_page;
        let start_count = 0;
        //===End pagination variable========


        return(
            <StaticLayout>
                <blog list related html />
                <Pagination className="users-pagination pull-right" bsSize="medium" maxButtons={10} first last next prev boundaryLinks items={pages} activePage={current_page} onSelect={this.changePage} />
            </StaticLayout>
        );  
    }

    changePage(page){
        alert(page);
        this.props.dispatch(push('/?page_no='+page))
    }


}


function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
    var queryParam = queryString.parse(ownProps.location.search);
    return { 
        blogListData: state.UserReducer.blogData,
        page: Number(queryParam.page_no) || 1,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({getBlogList: getBlogList}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (BlogList);
```

Plz let me know what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls/renders <BlogList />

Comment: I have updated code, plz check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch` is available to the component when you use connect only if you are not overriding it with the a custom function. which in your case is a `mapDispatchToProps` function. So what you can do is make the `push` action available as a prop to the component by adding it to the `mapDispatchToProps` function like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({getBlogList: getBlogList, push: push}, dispatch)
}
```

and use it like

```
changePage(page){
    alert(page);
    this.props.push('/?page_no='+page)
}
```

Comment: `this.props.history.push(location.pathname+'?page_no='+page)`  this works for me.... thanks #Shubham

Answer (score 0):

You can try hoisting the changePage into connect. I find this model easier to read and maintain.

```
function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
  var queryParam = queryString.parse(ownProps.location.search);
    return { 
      blogListData: state.UserReducer.blogData,
      page: Number(queryParam.page_no) || 1,
   }
}

const dispatch = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  changePage: (page) => {
    alert(page);
    dispatch(push('/?page_no='+page))
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch) (BlogList);
```

Comment: I did  same as you said, and export component like this  - >>>> `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, dispatch) (BlogList);
`   but now its giving error `this.props.getBlogList is not a function`,  but it is.

Comment: I think you have the arguments in the wrong place. checkout https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options